# Let a and b be relatively prime integers and let k be any integer. Show that a + bk and b are also relatively prime.

Tags: combinatorics

Let a and b be relatively prime integers and let k be any integer. Show that a + bk and b are also relatively prime.

IF a+bk and b are relatively prime that means their gcd is 1. But how do I prove that gcd(a+bk,b)=1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Let integer $d$ divides both $a+bk, b$

$\implies d$ divides $a+bk-k(b)=a$

$\implies d$ divides $a,b$

Comment: @CommanderShepard, observe that gcd$(a+bk,b)=$gcd$(a,b)$ which does not need to be $1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Try to start with a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ then try to get a linear combination of $a+bk$ and $b$.